# Making an SQL query more efficient

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that works, but it's taking at least 3 seconds to run so I think it can probably be faster. It's used to populate a list of new threads and show how many unread posts there are in each thread. I generate the query string before throwing it into `$db->query_read()`. In order to only grab results from valid forums, `$ids` is string with up to 50 values separated by commas.

The `userthreadviews` table has existed for 1 week and there are roughly 9,500 rows in it. I'm not sure if I need to set up a cron job to regularly clear out thread views more than a week old, or if I will be fine letting it grow.

Here's the query as it currently stands:

```
SELECT 
    `thread`.`title` AS 'r_title', 
    `thread`.`threadid` AS 'r_threadid', 
    `thread`.`forumid` AS 'r_forumid', 
    `thread`.`lastposter` AS 'r_lastposter', 
    `thread`.`lastposterid` AS 'r_lastposterid', 
    `forum`.`title` AS 'f_title', 
    `thread`.`replycount` AS 'r_replycount', 
    `thread`.`lastpost` AS 'r_lastpost', 
    `userthreadviews`.`replycount` AS 'u_replycount', 
    `userthreadviews`.`id` AS 'u_id',
    `thread`.`postusername` AS 'r_postusername', 
    `thread`.`postuserid` AS 'r_postuserid' 
FROM 
    `thread` 
INNER JOIN 
    `forum` 
    ON (`thread`.`forumid` = `forum`.`forumid`) 
LEFT JOIN 
    (`userthreadviews`) 
    ON (`thread`.`threadid` = `userthreadviews`.`threadid` 
    AND `userthreadviews`.`userid`=$userid) 
WHERE 
    `thread`.`forumid` IN($ids) 
    AND `thread`.`visible`=1 
    AND `thread`.`lastpost`> time() - 604800
ORDER BY `thread`.`lastpost` DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

An alternate query that joins the `post` table (to only show threads where user has posted) is actually twice as fast, so I think there's got to be something in here that could be changed to speed it up. Could someone provide some advice?

Edit: Sorry, I had put the EXPLAIN in front of the alternate query. Here is the correct output:
As Requested, here is the output generated by EXPLAIN SELECT:
[image: EXPLAINS Query]

Comment: Have you looked at the ouput of the EXPLAIN statement? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Can you please post the output of EXPLAIN SELECT?

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to post the explain result. I think I have to take a screencap.

Comment: I think this shows that I need an addition parameter when joining `userthreadviews`. I am not sure what that would be though.

Comment: Hi from the future! There are currently 188,482 rows in the `userthreadviews` table and nothing bad has happened. Everything is still working smoothly. Indexes are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have no indexes on joins / where (used key = NULL on explain), this is the reason why your queries are slow. You should index them in such a way :

```
CREATE INDEX thread_forumid_index ON thread(forumid);
CREATE INDEX userthreadviews_forumid_index ON userthreadviews(forumid);
```

Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, in my self-teaching of all things SQL I completely missed the part about creating and using indexes. Could you include a link to the documentation so I can better understand your suggestion?

Comment: I added an index on userid in the userthreadviews table, and now I'm getting: Query Time Elapsed: 0.00984406471252s

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [mysql explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) statement. It gives you a execution plan of your query.

Once you know the plan, you can check if you have got a index on the fields involved in the plan. If not, create them.

Perhaps the plan reveals details about how the query can be written in another way, such that the query will be more optimized.

Comment: why downvote? this is true! a comment more than an answer okey but this is true and I +1's just because of the downvote

Answer (score 1):

Try to index the table forumid if it is not indexed

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- move the conditions from the WHERE clause to the JOIN clause
- put the JOIN with the conditions *before* the other JOIN
- make sure you have proper indexes and that they are being used in the query (create the ones you'll need... too much indexes can be as bad as too few)

Here is my suggestion for the query:

```
SELECT 
    `thread`.`title` AS 'r_title',
    `thread`.`threadid` AS 'r_threadid',
    `thread`.`forumid` AS 'r_forumid',
    `thread`.`lastposter` AS 'r_lastposter',
    `thread`.`lastposterid` AS 'r_lastposterid',
    `forum`.`title` AS 'f_title',
    `thread`.`replycount` AS 'r_replycount',
    `thread`.`lastpost` AS 'r_lastpost',
    `userthreadviews`.`replycount` AS 'u_replycount',
    `userthreadviews`.`id` AS 'u_id',
    `thread`.`postusername` AS 'r_postusername',
    `thread`.`postuserid` AS 'r_postuserid' 
FROM
    `thread` 
    INNER JOIN (`forum`)
        ON ((`thread`.`visible` = 1)
        AND (`thread`.`lastpost` > $time)
        AND (`thread`.`forumid` IN ($ids))
        AND (`thread`.`forumid` = `forum`.`forumid`))
    LEFT JOIN (`userthreadviews`)
        ON ((`thread`.`threadid` = `userthreadviews`.`threadid`)
        AND (`userthreadviews`.`userid` = $userid))
ORDER BY
    `thread`.`lastpost` DESC
LIMIT
    0, 30
```

These are good candidates to be indexed:

```
- `forum`.`forumid`
- `userthreadviews`.`threadid`
- `userthreadviews`.`userid`
- `thread`.`forumid`
- `thread`.`threadid`
- `thread`.`visible`
- `thread`.`lastpost`
```

It seems you already have lots of indexes... so, make sure you keep the ones you really need and remove the useless ones.

Comment: Your query (with valid numbers in places of variables) is not working. No sql errors, it just starts loading and I have yet to get a result.

Comment: I had to restart my server after trying to run this query.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've reviewed it and I really made a stupid thing when including the conditions in the `LEFT JOIN` clause... because due to being a **LEFT** join it would include all the records anyway! Please, try the new query - I expect it will behave better. :-) Note that if you can calculate the `$time` in PHP, outside the query, it is another mini performance improvement.

Comment: By the way... you really need the `userthreadviews.userid = $userid` condition, when the **LEFT** join will always return all records from the previous join?

Comment: The entire query string is formed in PHP and then run through the query. I have `userthreadviews.userid = $userid` because only results related the the user viewing the page are important.

Comment: Then, shouldn't a normal INNER JOIN be used, instead of a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I need null results as well, as some threads do not have a corresponding threadview yet. You may be onto something but it's a bit outside the scope of my SQL knowledge. Adding an index sped up my query by about 100x.

Comment: Ok. I only got curious if my edited query crashes the server or simply works... :-)